# how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory

Tags: command-line, shell, bash

I want to glob every hidden file and directory, but not the current (`.`) and parent directory (`..`).

I am using bash.

Observe current behaviour:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  ...a  ...aa  ..a  ..aa  .a  .aa  .aaa  a
$ echo *
a
$ echo .*
. .. ...a ...aa ..a ..aa .a .aa .aaa
```

I would like `.*` to behave like this

```
$ echo .*
...a ...aa ..a ..aa .a .aa .aaa
```

There is the shell option `dotglob`

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
```

that works in a way; now I can use `*` to glob everything (hidden or not) but not `.` and `..`

```
$ echo *
...a ...aa ..a ..aa .a .aa .aaa a
```

but now I can't differentiate between hidden or not. Also, `.*` still globs `.` and `..`

```
$ echo .*
. .. ...a ...aa ..a ..aa .a .aa .aaa
```

Is there a way to make `.*` not expand to `.` and `..`?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43713/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-command

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use the `GLOBIGNORE` variable to hide the `.` and `..` directories. This does automatically also set the `dotglob` option, so `*` now matches both hidden and non-hidden files. You can again manually unset `dotglob`, though, this then gives the behavior you want.

See this example:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  a  .a  ..a
$ GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
$ shopt -u dotglob
$ echo * # all (only non-hidden)
a
$ echo .* # all (only hidden)
.a ..a
```

Note the following corner cases shown by numerous users in the comments:

- `.` and `..` are always ignored as long as `GLOBIGNORE` has a non-null value. `GLOBIGNORE=":" ; echo .*`, for instance, would work for the example above, even though it is less readable.
- If you want to match hidden *directories only* (and not all hidden files) and therefore glob with a trailing slash, `echo .*/`, you need to set `GLOBIGNORE='.:..:./:../'`, because the glob will match `./` and `../`, which must be excluded explicitly to prevent them from showing up in the result.

Comment: This only works if you include the glob in the command; `env GLOBIGNORE=". .." ls -a` returns `.` and `..` but `... ls -ad .*` doesn't.

Comment: I don't get this comment... The question was not about the ls command, but about a **glob** -- "including the glob in the command" is exactly what the OP wanted to do...

Comment: It's informational not critical.

Comment: No problem, I'm not afraid of criticism. It's just that I didn't understand the connection between the comment and my answer. But as I did also not understand your the connection between your answer and the original question that's consistent at least ;)

Comment: Yeah, I got caught up with trying to make extended globbing patterns work with `.` the way I think it should using `ls` as a canonical command and forgot about the details of the post.

Comment: I should add, this is a great answer and you've solved more than one problem that I've had in the past and have resorted to hacks to make work. I never knew about GLOBIGNORE before now.  BTW--edit your post in some inconsequential way.  For some reason my up-vote is not showing and when I try to add it, I get a dialog telling me that my vote's locked in unless the post is edited.

Comment: Thanks -- actually I found out about GLOBIGNORE only for this answer ;) I edited my post slightly, thanks in advance for voting.

Comment: @MarcelStimberg you can disable dotglob after setting GLOBIGNORE. that will then have the effect i want. please add that to your answer.

Comment: @lesmana you are completely right, I corrected my answer. Wonder why dotglob is automatically set in the first place...

Comment: @MarcelStimberg: because it's handy. Since `GLOBIGNORE` supercedes `dotglob`, by not including `.*` in `GLOBIGNORE`, bash presumes that you want to see dotfiles

Comment: Note that this does not work when prefixing the pattern with `./`.

Comment: Side note: `.` and `..` are always ignored as long as GLOBIGNORE has a non-null value. `GLOBIGNORE=:`, for instance, would work for the example above. That's less readable, of course, so I note this only for players of America's Fastest Growing Quiz Game ®, Bash Trivia ©

Answer (score 31):

The first glob below requires a leading dot and at least one additional non-dot character. These two globs together will match any possible hidden files, including files with more than one leading dot, but not `.` or `..`, which is exactly what you asked for.

```
ls -ld .[!.]* ..?*
```

Comment: That would also exclude `..foo`. The portable syntax is `.[!.]*`. `.[^.]*` is not standard (though supported by many shells)

Answer (score 9):

Are you just looking for files? Are you in a position to use `find`?

Something like (assuming GNU `find`):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -printf "%P\n"
```

Comment: Newline-delimiting can cause issues with filenames containing newlines; null-delimiting shouldn't.

Answer (score 9):

With `zsh`, `fish`, `pdksh`, and at least some of its derivatives like `mksh`, `posh`, ksh93 since ksh93u+m 2020-08-09, bash since 5.2:

```
echo .*
```

(the globs of those shells never expand `.` or `..`, which is the most sensible thing to do).

With older versions of `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
echo [.]*
```

(with `dotglob`, `.` and `..` are not expanded unless you use a glob that starts with a literal `.` as in `.*` or `dir/.*`, as otherwise things like `chmod +rwx -- *` would have unexpected consequences).

Or:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.
echo .*
```

(with `bash`, like for `dotglob` and for the same reason, as soon as `GLOBIGNORE` is non-empty, both `.` and `..` are automatically ignored in globs not contains slashes (and `dotglob` is enabled) and this time even with a literal `.` as above. Note that `GLOBIGNORE=/` for instance would have the same effect).

Note however that `.` and `..` would still be included in globs like `dir/.*` or `.*/file`.

With older versions of `ksh93`

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)' # or FIGNORE=.:..
echo .*
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to show hidden files/folders BUT `.` and `..` ?

Use this bash wildcard `{.[!.]*,..?*}`

**Sample Data**

You can try by generating sample data :

```
$ touch ...a  ...aa  ..a  ..aa  .a  .aa  .aaa  a
$ mkdir ...b  ...bb  ..b  ..bb  .b  .bb  .bbb  b
```

**Proof**

Below you can see the expected removed entries :

```
$ diff <(\ls -a) <(\ls -ad {.[!.]*,..?*})
1,3d0
< .
< ..
< a
11d7
< b
```

**Pro**

Useful to delete all hidden elements for example :

```
$ rm -rf .*
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'
rm: cannot remove directory: `..'

# <regenerate sample data here>

$ rm -rf {.[!.]*,..?*}
# No error
```

Comment: with modern bash you can factor out * `{.[!.],..?,}*`

Comment: what is the point in using braces expansion vs `.[!.]* ..?*`  (just a space between two globs)?

Comment: @maoizm If you want to specify files in a subfolder, then brace expansion makes more sense: `folder/{.[!.],..?}/*`. Note that the error-free `rm` is only a half-truth. Because the single semantik "all hidden files" is split into two different wildcards, it can result in errors if only one type of hidden folder exists: `rm: cannot remove '.[!.]*': No such file or directory` even though a file `...a` did exist.

Comment: @mxmlnkn now I see the point, this is indeed a non-obvious corner case

Answer (score 5):

Try `ls -A`. 
Here's an excerpt from [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

> **`-A`**, **`--almost-all`**
>
>   do not list implied
>   **`.`**
>   and
>   **`..`**

Comment: Plus 1, I was looking for how to hide the . and .. files from the ls ouput and stumbled on your answer. Thanks a lot Orso Grigio :)

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the original question, as it also lists non-hidden files, but exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -2):

```
ls -1a|egrep -v '^(\.|\.\.)$'
```

Comment: `ls` should *never* be parsed or used in scripts, and certainly not as a replacement to globbing.

Comment: Right, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more information

Comment: Also, you don’t need to specify the ``-1`` (one) option to ``ls`` when you’re piping the output or redirecting it into a file.