# Is the behaviour of .* to include . and .. defined in LSB or POSIX or some other specification?

Tags: shell, wildcards, standard, dot-files

Is the behavior of `.*` to include `.` and `..` defined in LSB or POSIX or some other specification?

Comment: for how to glob hidden files except current and parent directory see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from the [Single Unix specification version 2, volume ”Commands & Utilities", §2.13.3](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_013_003):

> If a filename begins with a period (`.`) the period must be explicitly matched by using a period as the first character of the pattern or immediately following a slash character. (…) It is unspecified whether an explicit period in a bracket expression matching list, such as `[.abc]` can match a leading period in a filename.

There is no exception that would make the second period in `..`, or the empty string following the only period in `.`, not matched by the wildcard in `.*`. Therefore the standard says that **`.*` matches `.` and `..`**, annoying though it may be.

The passage above describes the behavior of the shell (`sh` command). The section on the `glob` C library function refererences this passage.

The language is exactly the same in [version 3](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), also known as POSIX:2001 and IEEE 1003.1-2001, which is what most current systems implement.

Dash, bash and ksh93 comply with POSIX. Pdksh and zsh (even under `emulate sh`) don't.

In ksh, you can make `.*` skip `.` and `..` by setting `FIGNORE='.?(.)'`, but this has the side effect of making `*` include dot files. Or you can set `FIGNORE='.*'`, but then `.*` doesn't match anything.

In bash, you can make `.*` skip `.` and `..` by setting `GLOBIGNORE='.:..'`, but this has the side effect of making `*` include dot files. Or you can set `GLOBIGNORE='.*'`, but then `.*` doesn't match anything.

Comment: note: `bash` doesn't always comply with POSIX. only when it's invoked as `sh`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you mean the functionality in bash expansion about globignore. By default the bash expansion match . and .. but reading the man:

```
The  GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file names matching
   a pattern.  If GLOBIGNORE is set, each matching file name that also  matches  one  of
   the patterns in GLOBIGNORE is removed from the list of matches.  The file names ``.''
   and ``..''  are always ignored when GLOBIGNORE is set and not null.  However, setting
   GLOBIGNORE  to  a non-null value has the effect of enabling the dotglob shell option,
   so all other file names beginning with a ``.''  will match.  To get the old  behavior
   of  ignoring  file  names beginning with a ``.'', make ``.*''  one of the patterns in
   GLOBIGNORE.  The dotglob option is disabled when GLOBIGNORE is unset.
```

You can set the variable `GLOBIGNORE=.:..` so when you tipe something like this:

```
rm -r * .*
```

you are removing only the current directory. The POSIX standard only specify that . is the current directory and .. in the parent of the current directory. The special meaning of .* is interpreted by bash or other shells (or programs like grep).

Answer (score 0):

The [Linux man-page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/glob.7.html) references POSIX.2, 3.13.

Comment: Does the LSB require `man`, `man glob` or the man-pages to be present? I could not find man [here](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.html#TOCCOMMAND) (to my surprise).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the LSB 4.1 does not require `bash` and only `sh`.

For `sh` [it follows POSIX](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.html#SH) (with one minor non-relevant extension).