# How do I delete everything in a directory?

Tags: shell, rm, wildcards

How do I delete everything in a directory, including hidden files and directories?

Right now, I use the following:

```
rm -rf *
rm -rf .*
```

Comment: You can combine them to `rm -rf .* *`.

Comment: You can go one directory up and then run `rm -rf yourdirectory/*`

Comment: sorry missed the hidden directory part. The previous users solution covers that

Comment: That second option you posted is very dangerous. It will match the `..` directory, which will delete whatever is in the directory _above_.

Answer (score 19):

Simple and straight forward:

```
find -delete
```

Includes directories and hidden files. At least gnu-find knows `-delete`, your `find` may differ.

Comment: To avoid deleting the directory, use `find /path -delete -mindepth 1`.

Comment: @orodbhen: find -delete won't delete the directory, where you launch the command (as in the question with rm).

Answer (score 11):

The best answer is: Don't do that.  Recursively remove the directory itself, then recreate it as an empty directory.  It's more reliable and easier for other people to understand what you're trying to do.  When you re-create the directory it may have a different owner, group and permissions.  If those are important be careful. Also, if any running programs have open file handles (descriptors) on the directory then you won't want to remove it.  If none of those special cases apply, then it's simpler to remove the entire directory.

Comment: So how is that more easy. 'Be careful' isn't an answer. I wouldn't understand why somebody deletes a directory and rebuilds it again.

Comment: I added the phrase "as an empty directory", perhaps that's more clear.

Comment: No, it doesn't explain why you delete a directory and recreate it then. To the things to consider belongs, btw., date/time of creation too.

Comment: If that directory is the current working directory of some process, you may run into problems. Also, if you remove the directory, you remove information about its permissions and ownership.

Comment: What if the directory is a mount point? What if you don't have permission to remove the directory itself?

Comment: If it's a mount point then you can't remove it.  Good point.

Answer (score 9):

```
rm -rf -- * .[!.]* ..?*
```

Each of the three pattern expands to itself if it matches nothing, but that's not a problem here since we want to match everything and `rm -f` ignored nonexistent arguments.

Note that [`.*` would match `..`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/is-the-behaviour-of-to-include-and-defined-in-lsb-or-posix-or-some-other/1215#1215).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming bash 4+:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -rf -- *
##or:
rm -rf ./*
```

With dotglob enabled, `*` expands to all files and directories, even those that begin with `.` - but *doesn't* expand to `.` and `..`, so it is safe to use with `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

if you are in the directory:

`cd .. && rm -rf dir && mkdir dir && cd dir`

otherwise:

`rm -rf /path/to/dir && mkdir /path/to/dir`

Answer (score 2):

Oh my Zsh

```
rm -rf (.|)*
```

Again, this is for Zsh only.

Comment: Or `*(D)` (the `D` glob qualifier turns on the `glob_dots` option for this pattern).

Comment: Or `rm -rf {.,}*` (unlike bash, zsh doesn't include `.` and `..` into `{.,}*`, at least on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `find`. I think this is generally a good choice, when you have to dig through sub-directories.

```
find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: there is a -delete switch, so you can delete directories. (at least in gnu-find).

Comment: this won't delete subdirectories

Answer (score -2):

Try `rm -rf *?*`. This will delete normal and hidden files.

Comment: Not in any shell that I know of.

Comment: you are correct. it does not deletes sub-directories.

Comment: The problem is more likely to be that `*?*` will not match “dot” files/dirs (unless you have enabled the `dotglob` option in *bash*, the `GLOB_DOTS` option in *zsh*, or an equivalent for whatever shell you are using).