# What does .??* mean in a shell command?

Tags: wildcards, tar

The [following](http://dabase.com/e/01029/) command will `tar` all "dot" files and folders:

```
tar -zcvf dotfiles.tar.gz .??*
```

I am familiar with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), but I don't understand how to interpret `.??*`. I executed `ls .??*` and `tree .??*` and looked at the files which were listed. Why does this regular expression include all files within folders starting with `.` for example?

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) are not regular expressions.  In general, the shell will try to interpret anything you type on the command line that you don't quote as a glob.  Shells are not required to support regular expressions at all (although in reality many of the fancier more modern ones do, e.g. the `=~` regex match operator in the `bash` `[[` construct).

The `.??*` is a glob.  It matches any file name that begins with a literal dot `.`, followed by any two (not necessarily the same) characters, `??`, followed by the regular expression equivalent of `[^/]*`, i.e. 0 or more characters that are not `/`.

For the full details of shell pathname expansion (the full name for "globbing"), see the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).

Comment: Additional point: this is an attempt to write a glob which matches all of the dotfiles in a directory *except* the special entries `.` and `..`, which one normally does not want to do anything with.  It's not quite right; it doesn't pick up anything named '`.X`' where X is some character other than dot.  I don't think it's possible to write a single glob that matches *every* dotfile except `.` and `..`, but you can do it with two: `tar zcvf dotfiles.tar.gz .[!.] .??*` for instance.

Comment: @Zack: Thanks for the clarification. I posted a comment about that, but then deleted it. `ls .?` returned the same as `ls ..`, which meant there were no other entries in the folder matching the pattern `.?`. I would have done `.[^.]` for all `.?` files other than `..`.

Comment: @SabreWolfy If you read the POSIX spec carefully, that's actually an important difference between globs and regex: in bracket expressions, `[^abc]` in regex syntax means the same as `[!abc]` in glob syntax (i.e. `^` is replaced with `!` for globs).  Using `[^abc]` style syntax in a glob is not very portable because POSIX does not specify what it means, so some shells interpret it using regex-like semantics while others treat `^` as just a literal character.

Comment: @jw013: Thanks for the details. I must remember that glob != regexp :)

Comment: It just occurred to me that `.[!.]` may be left as a literal on the `tar` command line in the common case where there are no files that match that pattern.  Some shells let you control that behavior, e.g. with bash, `shopt -s nullglob` will make it vanish from the command line if it doesn't match anything, but that's not a universal feature.

Comment: @Zack With `bash` you also get the `dotglob` and `GLOBIGNORE` features.  With `GLOBIGNORE=.`, a simple `.*` should do.

Answer (score 9):

The `.??*` wildcard (*not* a regular expression, though it looks that way) translates into filenames that start with a period (`.`) , followed by two single characters (`??`), and then any number (zero or more) of other characters (`*`).

Maybe this page on [Wildcards in Filenames](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/wildcard.html) will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

To add to the other answers, a single `?` will translate to a single character filename and `??` will match filenames that has only two characters and so on.

```
[root@mercy testdir_2]# ls
ion  it  r
[root@mercy  testdir_2]# ls ?
r
[root@mercy  testdir_2]# ls ??
it
[root@mercy 1 testdir_2]# ls ???
ion
[root@mercy  testdir_2]#
```

Comment: Downvoter, could you comment please? Would be happy to get corrected, if I am wrong.

Comment: Your answer did not answer the question fully.