# How do I specify arguments to return all dot files, but not . and ..?

Tags: shell, tcsh, csh, dot-files

Normally dot files are not included for wildcard expansion:

```
% echo *
Applications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public bin
```

If I explicitly ask for dot files, I get them:

```
% echo * .*
Applications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public bin . .. .CFUserTextEncoding .DS_Store .Trash .adobe .bash_history .cups .gitconfig .gnupg .history .lesshst .netbeans .scanview.cfg .sqlite_history .ssh .swt .systemmodeler .tcshrc .viminfo
```

However I *also* get `.` and `..`.  I don't want those, for example if I'm passing to `du -s` where I want the size of every item in the directory.  Is there some pattern that gives me just what's in the current directory, and everything in the current directory without `.` and `..`?

I use tcsh.

*(With regard to the "This question may already have an answer here:" note above: no this question doesn't have an answer there, since that answer only works for bash.)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory)

Comment: not a duplicate as this question is for csh/tcsh while the other one was for `bash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tcsh` 6.17.01 and above:

```
set globdot
du -s -- *
```

With older ones:

```
du -s -- * .[^.]* ..?*
```

(interestingly, that works better than its POSIX counterpart (`* .[!.]* ..?*`) because in `tcsh` (and in `zsh` in `csh` emulation (`cshnullglob` option)), contrary to POSIX shells, those pattern that don't match any file get expanded to nothing instead of themselves)

With standard find:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -exec du -s {} +
```

Note that GNU `du` has a `-d` option to limit the depth at which dir disk usage are reported:

```
du -ad1
```

Comment: Interestingly, I have tcsh 6.17.00.  Indeed, the globdot doesn't work there.

Comment: The `du -s -- * .[^.]* ..?*` works, and covers odd cases included spaces in the names and dot dot names.  And it even works in bash.  Thanks!

Comment: On my `du`, `-a` cannot be combined with `-d`.  However `du -d1 .` does the trick.  Thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ls -A command to not enlist . and .. inside command substitution:

```
echo "`ls -A`"
```

Comment: `du *` will work even if there are names with spaces in the directory. `du \`ls -A\`` will not (and `du "\`ls -A\`"` will not work at all).

Comment: @derobert, why...? I've tried `du "\`ls -A\`"` in test directory and it seemed to work well.

Comment: Did you have multiple items in that directory? I'd expect it to work with 1, but fail with 2 or more. I guess its possible tcsh does something weird there...

Comment: In my case it worked fine even for `/etc` dir.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, that does work in tcsh. At least unless your filenames contain newlines, which is sufficiently uncommon that its probably ignorable.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use:

```
du -ks * .[^.]*
```

This way `.` and `..` are not matched and it should be fairly portable.

Comment: Indeed, this works in bash, and I think POSIX shell as well.

Comment: It will fail for some uncommon cases like `..filename`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a tcsh builtin, but depending on the version of find you have, there is a workaround like this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.' -exec du -s '{}' '+'
```

If your find doesn't do the `-exec COMMAND {} +` syntax, you can try for `-print0`/`xargs`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.' -print0 | xargs -0 du -s
```

Comment: `-exec {} +` is POSIX; `-maxdepth`, `-not`, `-print0` are not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple generic solution as it is shell dependent:

For tcsh or bash:

```
echo .[^.]*
```

For ksh:

```
echo .*
```

However, it will fail in Nykakin's case (files beginning with ..)

For a more generic answer, use "grep" or "find", like in:

```
ls -a|grep '^\.\(..\|[^\.]\)'
```

This works with all shells I know and doesn't have the Nykakin's case.
Also works with those following special cases that other solutions could fail:

```
.x
.x.
..x.
```

It means: Start with a dot, followed by at least 2 characters or a character that isn't a dot.

Answer (score 0):

a way (but may choke or have side effects on strange filenames, ie files whose name contain a newline! but also files containing `*` or a `"` or ... you get the picture ^^. Be *very* careful if using those way to list and use files)

```
$ for i in * .* ; do echo $i ; done | egrep -v '^\.$|^\.\.$' > /tmp/list_files_one_by_lines
$ while read a_file ; do echo something on "${a_file}" ; done < /tmp/list_files_one_by_lines
```

so you should better use : find

more exactly:

find . -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 some_command

this is why:

```
$ find . | egrep '^\.$|^\.\.$'
.
$ find . -mindepth 1 | grep '^\.$'
$
```

and the use of `-print0 | xargs -0 ....` allow to take care of almost every special characters that could occur in a filename (newline, quotes, ;, ctrl+z, you name it)