# (Why) is it bad to use ls -A to list hidden files?

Tags: ls, filenames

I want to list every file, including hidden files, in the current directory. I don't want to include the parent (..) and current (.) directory.

I found this:

[how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory)

At the end, someone states `ls -A` is the way to go, but it's downvoted. However, it seems to work. What's wrong with `ls -A`?

Comment: Is this discussion or (real) question?

Comment: `ls -A` is the correct answer to your question, but not to the question you linked to (that question was about listing _only_ hidden files and directories).

Comment: I want to know if this is supported everywhere or if there is a better way of doing what I want to achieve.

Comment: in fact, as of the latest version of the [POSIX-spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), `ls -A` is an officially specified option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ls -A` is the correct answer to your question, but not to the question you linked to (that question was about listing *only* hidden files and directories).

Comment: More precise is that question is about globbing, hidden files and directories with the exclusion of `.` and `..`, not about listing. Listing only those globbed entries is not the same as doing  `ls -A`, but this should be close enough for the OP.