# Linux: remove file*..but not file1 and file2

Tags: bash, rm

Usually on bash i did

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(filedontwantremove)
```

and remove all files except filedontwantremove

But if i want to remove all file except filedontwantremove
and "antotherfilewithatotaldifferentname"?

There is a find solution,but i prefer i thing like rm !()

Comment: `info bash` says: _"In the following description, a PATTERN-LIST is a list of one or more patterns separated by a '|' ..."_

Comment: There's also `GLOBIGNORE`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1174/70524

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(filedontwantremove|antotherfilewithatotaldifferentname)
```

Note however that extglob is usually on by default in interactive shells in bash.
Do this to find out if it is active:

```
$ shopt -p extglob
shopt -s extglob                    ### The -s means that it is set.
```

And execute this command to find out the part of the manual that explains what does a `!(pattern-list)` idiom do:

```
$ LESS=+/'If the extglob shell option is enabled' man bash
```

> ... a *pattern-list* is a list of one or more patterns separated by a |.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a `find` solution, and it's POSIX way:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f ! -name 'file[12]' -exec rm {} +
```

It's not quite like using globbing, since when it only filtered regular files.