# How to avoid copying “..” while using cp command in terminal?

Tags: shell, cp, dot-files

I am using CentOS7 and when I use command

```
cp /root/test/.* /root/test1
```

it also copies `..` which copies all the files and folder in the parent directory of the source.

How to avoid copying `.` and `..`?

Comment: Does this help? [how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory)

Comment: I've already given an answer but do you want to copy all of the files in the current directory or just the hidden ones? From your question, it's not clear as to whether you are just trying to copy only hidden files or all the files in the directory while excluding the directory itself and the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explicitly stated in the question whether you want to copy *only* hidden names, or whether you'd want to copy all files. Likewise whether you want to copy the contents of any subdirectories.  I'm going to assume that you want to copy *only* hidden name is the current directory (because that you seem to want to do with your command).

Your command would not copy all the files in the parent directory unless you also used the `-R` option with `cp` (or `-r` with GNU `cp`) to do a recursive copy.  Without the `-R` option, `cp` would complain about `.` and `..` being directories, but and would not copy them.

In the `bash` shell, set the `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable to the `:`-delimited list of names that you don't want the shell to expand filename globbing patterns to,

```
GLOBIGNORE='.:..'
```

then copy your files,

```
cp /root/test/.* /root/test1
```

To set `GLOBIGNORE` temporarily, just for the copy operation, use a sub-shell:

```
( GLOBIGNORE='.:..'; cp /root/test/.* /root/test1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard idiom for globbing all names beginning with a dot except `.` and `..` is `.??*`. So your command would be

```
cp /root/test/.??* /root/test1
```

Comment: What if file name is `.a`?

Comment: Exactly! How would I do that in such a case where filename is .a?