# What command would I use to list all files and directories, including hidden ones, except . and ..?

Tags: linux

Ok so, I know ls -a lists files including the hidden ones, and * command includes the elements I want to include. ls -I "*.." -I "*..." does not work as I have to use ls -a.

Comment: See [how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU ls has `--almost-all`, or `-A`, which lists all directory entries except for `.` and `..`:

```
   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..
```

```
$ touch foo bar baz
$ ls -A
bar  baz  foo
```

Otherwise, portably, you can use globs with a case statement:

```
for dirent in * .*; do
    case $dirent in
        .|..) continue ;;
        *)    [ -e "$dirent" ] && printf '%s\n' "$dirent" ;;
    esac
done
```