# Deleting a hidden file with linux command

Tags: terminal, command, line

I tried using `rm -rf .*` command to remove a hidden file and I am met with this error.

```
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '..'
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: [how to glob every hidden file except current and parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/how-to-glob-every-hidden-file-except-current-and-parent-directory)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you add the result of running `ls -A` in the directory holding the file you want to delete, what is the name of the file? Running your `rm -rf .*` will have deleted ALL files and directories starting with a dot (`.`). If that was in your home directory you'll have now lost all your configuration files. Time to restore from your backup - if you had one

Comment: Why not just use the filename?

Comment: `rm -rf .*` does not remove "a hidden file" but all of them in your current working directory. And hidden directories, if any, recursively. Are you sure you want this? It's a pretty dangerous command that I don't recommend to ever execute. Remove only the exact files and directories you want to. Also maybe consider using an interactive file manager, such as `mc` in terminals, or a graphical one.